# What happened with Iwao Kuroiwa and Yukinori Shinohara after the battle against Yoshimura?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

After the battle with Yoshimura at the end of the 2nd season of the anime, Iwao Kuroiwa and Yukinori Shinohara were baddly injured. One of the characters said one of the two was in a critical state. What happened with them? Is it mentioned in the manga or something if they survived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about anime, but in manga, Iwao Kuroiwa

> lost his left arm, which was replaced by prosthesis.

and Yukinori Shinohara

> suffered brain damage due to heavy blood loss, and ended up in vegetable state.

In short, both characters are alive, but battle with Owl led to consequences of varying severity.